# Find matrix of linear operator $\mathcal{A} : \mathcal{P_5}\rightarrow \mathcal{P_5},\mathcal{A}(p)=-2p+(3x-1)p^{'}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find matrix of linear operator $\mathcal{A} : \mathcal{P_5}\rightarrow \mathcal{P_5},\mathcal{A}(p)=-2p+(3x-1)p^{'}$

$\mathcal{P_5}$ is the space of polynomials with degree not greater than $5$.

$\mathcal{A}(p)=(-2p-p^{'})+3p^{'}x+0x^2+0x^3+0x^4+0x^5$

$$\mathcal{A}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        p_1  \\
        p_2  \\
        p_3  \\
        p_4  \\
        p_5  \\
        \end{bmatrix}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2p_1-p_1^{'}  \\
        3p_2^{'}  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

How to get matrix of $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: You’re not going to get very far with only five components in the vector on the lhs.

Comment: $\mathcal{P}_5$ is has dimension 6 and i guess $p'$ denotes the derivative of $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x) = ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$ be an arbitrary polynomial in $\mathcal{P}_5$. Then
$$\begin{align}
(\mathcal{A}p)(x)&= -2p(x)+(3x-1)p'(x) \\
&= -2p(x)+(3x-1)(5ax^4+4bx^3+3cx^2+2dx+e) \\
&=13ax^5+(10b-5a)x^4+(7c-4b)x^3\\
&\quad +(4d-3c)x^2+(e-2d)x-2f-e.
\end{align}$$

Using the canonical transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathcal{P}_5, (a,b,c,d,e,f)^T\mapsto p$ you can write $\mathcal{A}p = TBT^{-1}p$ where
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
        13 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -5 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & -4 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & -3 & 4 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}.$$